# Styling problems with new theme and IE8

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Kudos on the new theme; I like it.  I just thought I would bring some styling problems in Internet Explorer 8 to your attention.

1. House font does not work on menus in header (questions/tags/users, etc.).  It looks like it is falling back to arial.  `Ask Question` is wrapping around to the next line. 
   Actually, House font does not appear to be working at all in IE8.
2. Whiteboard ghost image does not appear in IE8.

Site seems to work fine in Firefox. OS is Windows 7 Enterprise.  IE8 is 8.0.7600.16385.

[image]

Comment: @Robert, I'm not able to reproduce this using IE8.0.7600.16385 with Win7 Home Premium.

Comment: @Jin: Could it be a security setting in IE8?

Comment: No repo for me either

Comment: @robert to clarify: we can't reproduce the font issue. As for the the background image, it's because I used CSS3 multiple background. I've used other CSS3 elements for the new deign since the vast majority of the users on this site use CSS3 capable browsers(according to our web stats)

Comment: I'm also getting the "ASK QUESTION" overlapping that bar across the screen.  It doesn't look good.

Comment: I'm also running IE8.0.7600.16385 and the layout is displaying correctly.

Comment: I've got nearly that same issue in IE8 on winXP. I was just about to ask about it, not that I really care.  I just wanted to see if you were using CSS3 to get those cool fonts.  The fonts are OK, but the background is all white.

Comment: Maybe if you used a jpg instead of a png for the background (no reason for png is there?)

Comment: Also happens for me in Firefox on Mac.

Comment: @jin, I'm not sure what you're doing for browser detection, but I'm assuming you do something to make sure that you do not use multiple backgrounds in IE 8 right - then apply some sort of patch?   http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_Multi_background_images__including_I-16839.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm IE8 on WinXP and

- ... House is working fine for me.  Perhaps you need to install it?  Although I don't think I installed it
- ghost image is likewise working for me.

Comment: OK.  I'll add some OS and IE8 details to the question.  Site works fine in Firefox, without the House font installed.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this on Firefox on Mac, see: [new design header bug](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/737/new-design-header-bug)

Comment: And now gone...

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this; in IE8 the font loads correctly for multiple members of our development team including me.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @robert the screenshot is not terribly helpful, what we need is repro steps -- none of us in Europe or the USA can repro this.

Comment: I just opened the site, that's all.

Comment: Works fine on my IE8 browser at home (Windows 7 Professional, same IE8 version, so either it's a browser setting at work, or something to do with the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Robert, while I can't reproduce the font glitch, I have updated the CSS for those who can't load the font: the navigation text will still be on one line, instead of wrapped to two.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the background glitch in IE8 on Windows XP - SP3 (tried with themes on and off).

Using Firebug in Firefox 3 for Linux I see under the container class:

`url("img/bg-doodle-bottom.png") no-repeat scroll left bottom, url("img/bg-doodle-top.png") no-repeat scroll center 38px transparent`

Using the developer tools with IE8 I don't see anything, img/bg-doodle-top.png is not rendered.

*note* I'm don't actually use IE8 in windows XP, but I did want to see whether or not the fonts would display OK in IE8 and only happened to notice that the background was missing.

Also, everything else appears normal. [image]