# new design header bug

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Ask Question link is wrapped](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-ask-question-link-is-wrapped)

The new design has a bug in my Firefox 3.6.13 - the "Ask Question" link is under "Questions" not on the right where it should be:

[image]

Screen resolution is 1440x900.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/688/styling-problems-with-new-theme-and-ie8